# Execute a dos command from an excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I want to be able to run this command:

rename "845528004679 (1).jpg" "000001-000 (1).jpg"

from an excel cell, the same as if I were to open up ms dos and paste it in there.

Basically i have a macro to pull me down file list, it takes the UPC digits and vlooks up a product SKU and then adds the numbering and extension, then it makes the rename command and  i want that to be executed without making another file or copy or pasting to another file

I haven't decided if I will add the file paths yet, just trying to find something similar I can work off of.

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/HV080756522.aspx

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this *using a DOS command* like that??

Comment: Don't know, just piecing things together to help myself out.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can use `FileCopy` then `Kill` to delete the original version (there are other ways):

```
FileCopy "source", "destination"
Kill "source"
```

If you specifically want to run a batch command then you might investigate `Shell` but if it is this simple then I would use the above code.

Comment: Or use Name as @GSerg suggests.